# Laravel - How to add variable to input name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to add a variable to input name, like this:

```
{!! Form::text('material[{{$num}}]', old('material[{{$num}}]'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=> '']) !!}
```

But in html it returns me this:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="" name="material[<?php echo e($num); ?>]" type="text">
```

And I don't understand what is the problem.

How can I solve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't nest `{{ }}`.

If you want to get this:

```
name="material[1]"
```

The correct syntax will be:

```
{!! Form::text('material[' . $num . ']', old('material[' . $num . ']'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=> '']) !!}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 {!! Form::text('material['.$num.']', old('material['.$num.']'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=> '']) !!}
```

When you are using `{{ }}` or `{!! !!}` means that you are already in php scope and you can put any php code

Answer (score 0):

If material is an array then it should be like

```
{!! Form::text('material[$num]', old('material[$num]'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=> '']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `{{}}` in `{!! !!}`

You use

```
{!! Form::text('material[' . $num . ']', old('material[' . $num . ']'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=> '']) !!}
```

Or

```
{!! Form::text('material[$num]', old('material[$num]'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=> '']) !!}
```